# How do I hide a line from exporting to gettext?

Tags: python-sphinx

Is there any way to mark a string as not exportable in gettext? I have such part in the documentation:

```
Some useful text:

* ``site.com``
* ``site.com/oauth/ely``
* ``site.com/oauth.php?provider=ely``
```

But when I run `make gettext`, it exports items from the list, which is unwanted. Any idea how to keep this formatting, but exclude strings from exporting to gettext?

Comment: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/ifconfig.html

Comment: @StevePiercy, ok it's an opportunity. But I still don't get how to make a condition about build mode. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: Please elaborate on what don't you understand that is not in the documentation.